# Get count of longest list inside a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, count

I have the following structure:

```
class Attribute
{
   List<Value> values;
}    

List<Attribute> attributes;
```

I need to get the Count of the longest `List<Value>` from the list of attributes.
Is there a simple solution using Linq?

I already tried two nested loops, which is not very performant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var max = attributes.Max(a => a.values.Count)
```

Comment: how can i get the list with the highest count?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the list with Maximum size using the `Count` attribute.

```
var max = attributes.Max(lst=>lst.values.Count);
```